# R - chart Y,X over categories Z, some categories as points others as lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, line, categories, point

In a plot of  Y and X over categories Z, I would like for categories to be represented by points of different collor, except for one category, which I would like to be displayed as a line connecting the points.

Here is the data and what I have so far:

```
library(ggplot2);library(reshape);library(scales);library(directlabels)
dat <- read.csv("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4329509/Fdat_graf.csv")
dat_long <- melt(dat, id="ano")
p <- qplot(ano,value, data=dat_graf_long, colour=variable)+   
scale_y_log10(breaks=c(.1,1,10,100,500,1000),labels = comma) + 
scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(from=1960, to=2010, by=10))  + 
theme_bw()
direct.label(p)
```

I would like for the "Lei_de_Moore" category to be represented by a line, as in this example (done in Stata):

[image]

Also, I would like to change a few things (maybe I should ask tem in different topic?):

- Change the style of the graph colors more "vivid", as in the Stata
  example
- Change the Y aixis. I just want plain Numbers in non-scientific
  notation form. I used the labels="comma", but I don't want the coma
  itself. Ideally I would like the comma to be the decimal place
  separator.

EDIT: I had asked another question on how to embed the legend for this graph (this post: [Legend as text alongside points for each category and with same collor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25612656/legend-as-text-alongside-points-for-each-category-and-with-same-collor))

Comment: Did you delete your earlier identical question? (You should.)

Comment: Thanks, I edited that question (and this one) to avoid redundancy. I think as separate questions they will be more useful for others. Let me know if you and others still think that it should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can mix geoms if you use `ggplot` and pass only a subset of the data to different geoms. Here you can pass everything in `dat_long` to `geom_point` except rows where `variable` is `Lei_de_Moore`, and then pass only those `dat_long` rows to `geom_line` in a different call.

```
p <- ggplot(dat_long, aes(ano, value, color=variable)) + 
    geom_point(data=dat_long[dat_long$variable != 'Lei_de_Moore',]) + 
    geom_line(data=dat_long[dat_long$variable == 'Lei_de_Moore',]) + 
    scale_y_log10(breaks=c(.1,1,10,100,500,1000),labels = comma) + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(from=1960, to=2010, by=10))  + 
    theme_bw()
```

For colors, have a look at `RColorBrewer` package palettes. Install the package and use `?brewer.pal` to see some more options. For example, this one might work:

```
p <- p + scale_color_brewer(palette="Set1")
```

For the y-axis labels, you'll probably have to hack something together. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035786/ggplot2-y-axis-label-decimal-precision). So you could do something like this:

```
fmt <- function(){
    f <- function(x) sub(".", ",", as.character(round(x,1)), fixed=T)
    f
}


p <- ggplot(dat_long, aes(ano, value, color=variable)) + 
    geom_point(data=dat_long[dat_long$variable != 'Lei_de_Moore',]) + 
    geom_line(data=dat_long[dat_long$variable == 'Lei_de_Moore',]) + 
    scale_y_log10(breaks=c(.1,1,10,100,500,1000), labels=fmt()) + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(from=1960, to=2010, by=10))  + 
    theme_bw() +
    scale_color_brewer(palette="Set1")
```